# Getting error while parsing string to datetime?

Tags: parsing, datetime

Getting error while parsing string to datetime.

```
string datestring = "111815";
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(datestring);
```

I also tried using, Parse, ExactParse with/without culture specificinfo.

I'm still getting the error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Please suggest the correct solution.

Comment: Please show *exactly* what you did with `ParseExact`. If you specify the right format string, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the right format string when you call `ParseExact`. In your case, it looks like this is month-day-year, without any separators, and with a 2-digit year (blech). So you'd parse it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("111815", "MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

If you're in control of the format at all, I'd *strongly* recommend `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of this ambiguous (due to the 2-digit years) and US-centric (due to month/day/year) format.

Comment: Hey..Thank you so much. I did try the same earlier but it did not work. Now it does.  Actually i am reading it from text file which is not created by third person so can do much about. But thank you it worked.